# dynamic set the vim option by key map,but some thing wrong

Tags: vim

I want to reset the font size by some key.
but it can not run well.
can you fix my code to achieve function.
or give me other method to achieve the same function.
thank you very much!

---

this is my designed script.

```
noremap <C-KPlus> :set guifont=substitute(&guifont,'w\(\d+\)','\="w" . (submatch(1)+1)','g')<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to try this out interactively using `:echo`:

```
:echo substitute('foobar-w20','w\(\d+\)','\="w" . (submatch(1)+1)','g')
foobar-w20
```

No, that didn't match. Ah, the multiplier for the `\d` must be `\+` instead of `+`:

```
:echo substitute('foobar-w20','w\(\d\+\)','\="w" . (submatch(1)+1)','g')
foobar-w21
```

We can remove the re-insertion of the `w` prefix by starting the match only after it with `\zs`.

```
:echo substitute('foobar-w20','w\zs\(\d\+\)','\=submatch(1)+1','g')
foobar-w21
```

The `:set` command takes a literal string, not an *expression* to be evaluated. We have to either use `:execute`, or use the handy fact that `:let` can be used to modify `&options`:

```
:noremap <C-KPlus> :let &guifont=substitute(&guifont,'w\zs\(\d\+\)','\=submatch(1)+1','g')<CR>
```

Neither `:set` nor `:let` allow a range, which would be inserted in visual mode. I think this mapping should only apply to *normal mode*, so use `:nnoremap`. And we don't need that long expression shown, so `<silent>`:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-KPlus> :let &guifont=substitute(&guifont,'w\zs\(\d\+\)','\=submatch(1)+1','g')<CR>
```

BTW, on Windows, the size seems to be encoded in a `h42` suffix, so let's handle that, too. Our previous refactoring now really helps:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-KPlus> :let &guifont=substitute(&guifont,'[hw]\zs\(\d\+\)','\=submatch(1)+1','g')<CR>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. The `\zs` makes Vim match what's before it, but doesn't actually include it. See `:h /\zs` for details.